# Rails 3 path for edit and new actions in a basic form view

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following routes:

```
resources :categories do
  resources :articles
end
```

And the following views:

```
# edit.erb and new.erb files:
<%= render :partial => 'form' %>

# top of _form.html.erb file:
<%= form_for category_article_path(@article.category, @article) do |f| %>
```

But I have some troubles with the given path.  I work with Rails 3.  Here is an example of error that I get when testing:

> undefined method `category' for
>   nil:NilClass

What is the basic way to write a such path?  Many thanks.

Comment: Your @article is nil so i think you have to find @article first.

Comment: I think the solution is to use: <%= form_for([@article.category, @article]) do |f| %>

Answer (score 1):

Just pass a freshly newed up article (with an existing category) instance to the view.